Example of a system which has both rheonomic and conservative constraint?

Generally speaking, rheonomic constraints are dissipative, although there are exceptions.

This was given in classical Mechanics by Rana and Joag
So, I was wondering what are those exceptions. If possible please explain why it is rheonomic as I expect that it will be far easy to know why it is dissipative.

Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/493900/2451

The Wikipedia article Rheonomous almost gives an example.
A rheonomic constraint has an explicit time dependence. So a pendulum with a moving pivot has such a constraint. The example has the pivot moving horizontally. This will accelerate the bob. It is not conservative.
But suppose the pivot moved along a circular arc. The pendulum has length $l$. Construct a pendulum of length $2l$. Make the pivot of the first pendulum match the motion of the point halfway down the longer string. With the proper initial condition, the short pendulum will match the motion of the long pendulum. This constraint is rheonomic and conservative.

I am by no means sure that this is a type of the cases considered by the authors.
Let us focus on a point of mass $m>0$ constrained to move along a frictionless straight line. This line stays in a horizontal plane and rotates around the vertical axis $z$, around the origin $O$ on the line, with a known constant angular velocity $\Omega>0$. The constraint explicitly depends on time. In particular
$$\vec{x}(t,s) = s\cos (\Omega t) e_x + s \sin(\Omega t) e_y$$
where $s$ is the coordinate of the point along the line with origin $O$.
Let us assume that the reference frame where the line rotates is inertial and write down the Lagrangian of the point using the coordinate $s$ on the line itself as Lagrangian coordinate.
With trivial computations,
$$L(s, \dot{s}) =\frac{m}{2}\dot{\vec{x}}^2=  \frac{m}{2}\dot{s}^2+\frac{m\Omega^2}{2}s^2.$$
Hence, in spite of the fact that the constraint explicitly depends on time,
the Lagrangian does not.
This implies that the Hamiltonian function constructed out of the above Lagrangian:
$$H(s, \dot{s}) = \frac{m}{2}\dot{s}^2-\frac{m\Omega^2}{2}s^2,$$
is a constant of motion.
The crucial point is that here $H$ is not the mechanical energy evaluated in the reference frame where the lines rotates, but it turns out to be the energy in the (non inertial) reference frame at rest with the line.

First of all, in my experience the only times I ever see the words "rheonomic" and "scleronomic" are in classical dynamics texts.  In my world, anyway, they are not useful terms.
Nonetheless: first consider this example: a mass on a frictionless surface constrained to move by $x = \sin\omega t)$.  Because it is non-physical to apply position constraints like this (as opposed to forces) these constraints can add or subtract energy from the system.  It's also poor practice in simulation because the forces can become unbounded.
Here is maybe an example you seek. [note: edited/changed from a previous poor answer.]  An ideal spring with constant $k$ is pivoted on one end to a moving point on a rotating turntable (not the center of rotation). The other end is connected to a mass $m$. The turntable rotates with constant speed $\omega$ such that the $(x,y)$ coordinates of the pivot are given by $x = R \cos(\omega t)$, $y = R \sin(\omega t)$.  The initial position and velocity of the mass are unspecified, but IF they are consistent with circular motion AND the initial spring stretch exactly corresponds to the centripetal force $m R \omega^2 $ necessary to maintain the motion, then the system energy will remain constant as the mass moves in a circle.  Other more general initial conditions could lead to energy loss or gain as the mass oscillates around the pivot.

Look at this example

a mass is connected with a rod to a joint at point A. we move the point A with arbitrary function $~x(t)~$
the constraint equation is:
$$ g:=x(t)^2+y^2-L^2=0 $$
this   constraint equation is time dependent and "state" dependent
